# Insert date/time into Access database

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm using ASP.NET/VB and I'm trying to insert a date and time into an Access date/time field, but I'm getting an error (Data type mismatch in criteria expression). Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
Dim myDate As Date = Now()
Dim myIns1 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tableCourse (date_submitted) VALUES (?)", myConn)
myIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myDate", myDate)
myIns1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Not sure why I'm getting the error, and not quite sure if this is even the correct way to approach inserting the current date. From looking at other similar questions it appears there are a few different ways to do this, but my technical knowledge is kind of limited so I'm having a hard time figuring it out (in other words deciphering the answers that use technical terms I know nothing about).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could skip the parameter altogether and just write the NOW function directly into the query.

```
Dim myIns1 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tableCourse (date_submitted) VALUES (NOW())", myConn)
myIns1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

<strike>This answer (the one above) is probably the better solution, but the reason why the original code didn't work is because the parameter wasn't named. You could try this:</strike>

```
Dim myDate As Date = Date.Now
Dim myIns1 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tableCourse (date_submitted) VALUES (@myDate)", myConn)
myIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myDate", myDate)
myIns1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Named parameters don't work with OleDb. They work on position only. It didn't work earlier because the value being passed wasn't a DateTime. More here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/92/MS-Access-Date-and-Time-with-ASP.NET

Comment: Mike, you're right when you say that the parameters only work positionally. However, you say that it didn't work "because the value being passed wasn't a DateTime". It most certainly was a DateTime. The ToOADate() function converts the value from a DateTime to a Double.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

```
Dim myDate As Date = Now()
```

to

```
Dim myDate As DateTime = Now()
```

MS Access does not offer a DATE datatype, only DATETIME.

Comment: Date and DateTime (if the System namespace is being imported) mean the exact same thing in VB.NET.

Comment: ["The `DATETIME` data type... synonyms are `DATE`, `TIME`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015(office.10).aspx#acintsql_datatypes)